# insert select failed in oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g, toad

hello I'm trying to make this insert massive but it does not work, not even throw me some error or warning

idproduct, precio and fkproovedor variables are brought from another table

```
DECLARE
RAN_PRODUCT   NUMBER;
RAN_CANT      NUMBER;
NVENTA        NUMBER;
MVENTA        NUMBER;
MT            NUMBER;
BEGIN
SELECT MIN (IDVENTA) INTO NVENTA FROM marcos.VENTA;

SELECT COUNT (IDVENTA) INTO MVENTA FROM MARCOS.VENTA;



FOR loop_one IN 1 .. 10
LOOP
  FOR loop_TWO IN 1 .. 2
  LOOP
     SELECT (1 + ABS (MOD (DBMS_RANDOM.random, 50)))
       INTO RAN_PRODUCT
       FROM DUAL;

     SELECT (1+ABS(MOD(dbms_random.random,10)))
       INTO RAN_CANT
       FROM DUAL;

     INSERT INTO marcos.DETALLEVENTA
        SELECT SEQ_DTEVENTA.NEXTVAL AS IDDETAVENTA,
               PRECIO AS PRECIO,
               RAN_CANT AS CANTIDAD,
               RAN_PRODUCT AS FKPRODUCTO,
               FKPROOVEDOR AS FKPROVEEDOR,
               NVENTA AS FKVENTA
          FROM MARCOS.PRODUCTO
         WHERE IDPRODUCTO = RAN_PRODUCT;
  END LOOP;


  NVENTA := NVENTA + 1;
END LOOP;

COMMIT;
EXCEPTION
WHEN OTHERS
THEN
  DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('Se ha producido un error');
  ROLLBACK;
```

END;

Comment: if doesnt give you an error why doesnt work?

Comment: What debugging have you done? Do you have matching products with IDs in the range 1-50? Do you see an error if you remove the (almost always wrong) `EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS` section, or at least add a `RAISE` after the rollback? (I'd *guess* that the columns in `DETALLEVENTA` might not match the order you're selecting them in and you're getting an implicit conversion error, but without the actual error and table definitions, who knows. Maybe there is just no data.)

Answer (score 1):

Use simple INSERT ... SELECT statement instead of PL/SQL code, like this

```
INSERT INTO DETALLEVENTA( IDDETAVENTA,PRECIO,CANTIDAD,FKPRODUCTO,FKPROVEEDOR,FKVENTA )
SELECT SEQ_DTEVENTA.NEXTVAL AS IDDETAVENTA,
       PRECIO AS PRECIO,
       RAN_CANT AS CANTIDAD,
       RAN_PRODUCT AS FKPRODUCTO,
       FKPROOVEDOR AS FKPROVEEDOR,
       (SELECT MIN (IDVENTA) FROM marcos.VENTA) AS FKVENTA
FROM PRODUCTO p
JOIN (
    SELECT (1 + ABS (MOD (DBMS_RANDOM.random, 50))) as RAN_PRODUCT,
           (1+ABS(MOD(dbms_random.random,10)))  as RAN_CANT
    FROM (
        select 1 from dual connect by level <= 10 * 2
    )
) x 
ON p.IDPRODUCTO = x.RAN_PRODUCT
```

Comment: It is already solved, although there is no that is what it modifies, maybe it was simple human stupidity
thanks for your help